# Managing python dependencies with spark on google cloud dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have written a Spark script that depends on `six` and various other python packages.

```
$ cat ./test_package/__init__.py
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen

def download_size(url):
    return len(urlopen(url).read())
```

As such, I have written a `setup.py` which states such dependencies.

```
$ cat ./setup.py
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name="Test App",
    packages=['test_package'],
    version="0.1",
    install_requires=['six>=1.0'],
```

Then in my spark script, I have code which requires the package

```
$ cat spark_script.py
#!/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit
from pyspark import SparkContext
from glob import glob
from test_package import download_size

sc = SparkContext()
sc.addPyFile(glob('dist/Test_App-*.egg')[0])

...

sc.parallelize(urls).map(download_size).collect()
```

If I run

```
$ ./test.py
```

It works fine. However, if I try to use python3,

```
$ PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 ./test.py
```

The master node is able to import `test_package`, but in the middle of the mapreduce I get this on each worker node:

```
  File "/hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/sam/appcache/application_1487279780844_0041/container_1487279780844_0041_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 419, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "./Test_App-0.1-py2.7.egg/test_package/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: No module named 'six'
```

How do I manage python dependencies on an Google cloud dataproc provisioned Apache spark cluster?

Comment: A related question (esp. for those who came via search): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745868/how-do-i-install-python-libraries-automatically-on-dataproc-cluster-startup

Answer (score 1):

Since worker tasks will run on worker nodes and you only manually installed your extra python packages, the worker nodes don't have the same configuration available as your master node.

You should use [Dataproc initialization actions](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/init-actions) to run your customization scripts on all nodes of the cluster at cluster-deployment time. For environment variables like `PYSPARK_PYTHON` you probably need to append those settings to `/etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh`.

Comment: "You only manually installed your extra python packages" however the egg file is added to the spark context with `sc.addPyFile(glob('dist/Test_App-*.egg')[0])`, and the `setup.py` lists the required packages, therefore I would expect that each worker would receive, unpack, and install the egg file. Why does this only happen with python 2?

Comment: Is packaging python dependencies in an egg file considered a more elegant solution than running a configuration shell script on each machine? It would seem so. Let me know if you feel differently.